# how to add resourcehandler in spring mvc 4 java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am adding resourceHandler in spring mvc 4 configuration but it not working. when i am adding this eclipse ide gives error and shows hint to remove @Override
here is my code

```
package net.codejava.spring.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
            "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

}

}
```

ApplicationContextConfig:

```
package net.codejava.spring.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import  org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.codejava.spring")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {



 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

  @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
 public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}


@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("");

    return dataSource;
}


private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    return properties;
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
        SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
            sessionFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "userDao")
public UserDAO getUserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    return new UserDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
  }
 }
```

and can you explain me why above class is not exteding WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to your `ApplicationContextConfig` class definition, then you can override/add the resource handler

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.codejava.spring")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/images/");
}
```